# How to show different select option in listview Jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, html, listview, jquery-mobile

I have a listview that i select a country in a preference menu.
When i select suppose USA i have to change another listview that has the same items as the first one to show the select item from the preference menu(USA).

i already have stored in a global variable what the user chose from the preference menu.
all i have to do is change the listview item to show the one he selected..

```
 <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="SLSelectPaisConsulta" class="select">Elegir el pais</label>
                <select name="SLSelectPaisConsulta" id="SLSelectPaisConsulta">
              <!--Aca Se Cargan Dinamicamente Los Paises En las consultas de clima-->
                </select>
```

Comment: Select menu not a list view.

Comment: Your question is very unclear.mind showing us some code?